# How can I parse a variable into multiple columns according to multiple conditions in R?

Tags: r, string-parsing

I'm new to R, so please bear with me. I am looking at incarceration data, and have a variable `conviction`, which is a messy string that looks like this:

```
[1] "Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute"                                                                         
[2] "Aggravated Assault"                                                                                      
[3] "Ct. 1: Possession of prohibited object; Ct. 2: criminal forfeiture"                                      
[4] "Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking; Cts. 7, 8 Unlawful contact; Ct. 11: Involuntary Servitude; Ct. 36: Smuggling"
```

Ideally, I want to do two things. First, I want to parse on `Ct.` into multiple columns. For the first three rows, the data would look like this:

```
     convictions                              conviction_1                      conviction_2                    
[1,] "Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute"        "Conspiracy to distribute"        NA                   
[2,] "Aggravated Assault"                     "Aggravated Assault"              NA                   
[3,] "Ct. 1: Possession of prohibited object" "Possession of prohibited object" "criminal forfeiture"
```

but things get hairy when I get to the third row, because I would want to parse the first part of the string(`Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking`) into 6 columns, and then `Ct. 7,8: Unlawful contact` into 2 more columns.

The second part is that I then want to generate a variable `convictions_total` which would find the highest number in the `conviction` string that follows after `Ct:`. for the three example entries I included here, `convictions_total` would look like:

```
[1]  1  2 36
```

This is the code I used to parse a much more straight-forward string variable, but I'm unsure how to tweak it for this variable:

```
cols <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(data$convictions`,",",Inf))
colnames(cols) <- paste0("conviction_",rep(1:length(cols)))
data <- cbind(data,cols)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going down a two-day rabbit hole, I figured out a tidy version of @LMc's  code, which ended up working better because calling `plyr` was messing up other code I had written:

```
test_data <- 
  tibble(id = 1:5, 
         convictions = c("Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute"    ,                                                                     
                         "Aggravated Assault"              ,                                                                        
                         "Ct. 1: Possession of prohibited object; Ct. 2: criminal forfeiture"  ,                                    
                         "Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking; Cts. 7, 8 Unlawful contact; Ct. 11: Involuntary Servitude; Ct. 36: Smuggling 50 grams",
                         "Ct. 1: Conspiracy; Cts. 2-7: Wire Fraud; Cts. 8-28:  Money Laundering"))
test_data <- test_data %>% 
  mutate(c2 = convictions) #this just duplicates the original variable convictions because I want to preserve it

test_data <- test_data %>%
  separate_rows(c2, sep = ";") %>%
  mutate(c2 = str_remove(c2, "Ct(s)?(\\. )(\\d|-|:|,|\\s)+")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(conviction_number = paste0("c_", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c2, names_from = conviction_number) 


test_data <- test_data %>% 
  mutate(c2 = convictions) #again, just preserving the original variable

test_data <- test_data %>%
  separate_rows(c2, sep = ";") %>% 
  mutate(total_counts = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(str_extract(c2, "((?<=\\-)\\d+)")), str_extract(c2, "\\d+"), str_extract(c2, "((?<=\\-)\\d+)")))) %>% 
  mutate(total_counts = ifelse(is.na(total_counts), 1, total_counts)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice_max(total_counts)
```

which produces the following dataframe:

```
     id convictions                                                  c_1                c_2           c_3            c_4          c2                 total_counts
  <int> <chr>                                                        <chr>              <chr>         <chr>          <chr>        <chr>                     <dbl>
1     1 Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute                              Conspiracy to dis~  NA            NA             NA          "Ct. 1: Conspirac~            1
2     2 Aggravated Assault                                           Aggravated Assault  NA            NA             NA          "Aggravated Assau~            1
3     3 Ct. 1: Possession of prohibited object; Ct. 2: criminal for~ Possession of pro~ " criminal f~  NA             NA          " Ct. 2: criminal~            2
4     4 Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking; Cts. 7, 8 Unlawful contact; Ct.~ Human Trafficking  " Unlawful c~ " Involuntary~ " Smuggling~ " Ct. 36: Smuggli~           36
5     5 Ct. 1: Conspiracy; Cts. 2-7: Wire Fraud; Cts. 8-28:  Money ~ Conspiracy         " Wire Fraud" " Money Laund~  NA          " Cts. 8-28:  Mon~           28
```

The first chunk of code parses the counts into separate rows, and then pivots back to the `c_` columns. The second code chunk does the same parsing, but then looks across each entry to parse out the digits, instead of the words.

`//d+` looks for any digit, but it turns out I had data that looked like `Cts. 2-7` where I wanted the value 7, and not 2.

`((?<=\\-)\\d+)"))` Looks for the hyphen, and then parses the digits after it. If there is no hyphen, it defaults back to `\\d+`.

Finally, `slice_max` collapses the data down to 1 entry per ID based on the highest value of `total_counts`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for your example without using much regular expression, mostly just digit extraction or other string detection:

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(plyr)

convictions_total <- sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(convictions, "\\d+"), 
                            function(x) max(as.numeric(x), 1))
convictions_split <- strsplit(convictions, ";")


reps <- lapply(convictions_split, FUN = function(x) {
    sapply(x, FUN = function(i) {
      num <- paste(stringr::str_extract_all(i, "[\\d+\\-,]")[[1]], collapse = "")
      # "-" indicates a range: take largest value
      if (stringr::str_detect(num, "-")){
        stringr::str_extract_all(num, "\\d+") %>% 
          unlist() %>% 
          as.numeric() %>%
          max() %>%  
          return()
      # "," indicates a sequence: get length of sequence
      } else if(stringr::str_detect(num, ",")){
        stringr::str_count(num, ",") + 1 %>% 
          as.numeric() %>%
          return()
      # otherwise return 1
      } else {
        return(1)
      }
    })
  })

convictions_str <- lapply(convictions_split, 
                          function(x) gsub(".*\\d:?\\s(.*)$", "\\1", x))

df <- purrr::map2(convictions_str, reps, rep) %>% 
  plyr::ldply(rbind) %>% 
  cbind(convictions_total, .) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::rename_with(~ gsub("X", "conviction_", .x), starts_with("X"))
```

**Output**

```
  convictions_total                    conviction_1        conviction_2      conviction_3
1                 1        Conspiracy to distribute                <NA>              <NA>
2                 1              Aggravated Assault                <NA>              <NA>
3                 2 Possession of prohibited object criminal forfeiture              <NA>
4                36               Human Trafficking   Human Trafficking Human Trafficking
       conviction_4      conviction_5      conviction_6     conviction_7     conviction_8
1              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>             <NA>             <NA>
2              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>             <NA>             <NA>
3              <NA>              <NA>              <NA>             <NA>             <NA>
4 Human Trafficking Human Trafficking Human Trafficking Unlawful contact Unlawful contact
           conviction_9 conviction_10
1                  <NA>          <NA>
2                  <NA>          <NA>
3                  <NA>          <NA>
4 Involuntary Servitude     Smuggling
```

**Data**

```
convictions <- c("Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute",
                 "Aggravated Assault",
                 "Ct. 1: Possession of prohibited object; Ct.: 2 criminal forfeiture",
                 "Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking; Cts. 7, 8 Unlawful contact; Ct. 11: Involuntary Servitude; Ct. 36: Smuggling")
```

---

**How it works**

1. `convictions_total` is simple to extract by using `stringr::str_extract_all` to take all the numbers from each row in `convictions`. This returns a list of vectors. `sapply` then takes the maximum from each vector in the list and returns a vector.
2. `reps` is a list where the elements correspond to the elements of `convictions` and it stores a numerical vector of how many times to repeat each conviction count.

The code works by first splitting `convictions` into a list of vectors where the vectors contain the following extracted information: digits (`\\d+`), dashes (`\\-`), and commas (`,`). The logic works by searching these string extractions:

- First, if it finds a `"-"` in the conviction count then that indicates a range and again it takes the largest value. For example `"Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking"` will return `6`.
- Next, if it does not find a `"-"`, but instead `","` that denotes a counting delimiter. So it counts the number of comma delimiters and adds one. For example `"Cts. 7, 8 Unlawful contact"` will return `2`
- Everything else is assumed to be repeated only once since it's not a sequential list or a range.

```
reps
[[1]]
Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute 
                              1 

[[2]]
Aggravated Assault 
                 1 

[[3]]
Ct. 1: Possession of prohibited object             Ct.: 2 criminal forfeiture 
                                     1                                      1 

[[4]]
    Ct. 1-6: Human Trafficking     Cts. 7, 8 Unlawful contact  Ct. 11: Involuntary Servitude 
                             6                              2                              1 
             Ct. 36: Smuggling 
                             1
```

4. `convictions_str` just extracts the actual conviction information. For example, from `"Ct. 1: Conspiracy to distribute"` the code will extract `"Conspiracy to distribute"` and so on for all the convictions.

```
[[1]]
[1] "Conspiracy to distribute"

[[2]]
[1] "Aggravated Assault"

[[3]]
[1] "Possession of prohibited object" "criminal forfeiture"            

[[4]]
[1] "Human Trafficking"     "Unlawful contact"      "Involuntary Servitude"
[4] "Smuggling"
```

At this point `reps` and `convictions_str` have a related structure:

- `convictions_str[[1]][1]` should be repeated `reps[[1]][1]` times
- `convictions_str[[1]][2]` should be repeated `reps[[1]][2]` times

5. `purrr::map2` takes advantage of this structure using the `rep` function to repeat the elements in `convictions_str` by the values stored in `reps` and outputs a list. `plyr::ldply` row binds this list filling with `NA` since not everyone has the same number of convictions. `cbind` adds the column `convictions_total`, and `dplyr::rename_with` changes the column names.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for such a thorough explanation. I'm realizing there is 1 hitch: there are a few entries in the data where there is no `Ct.:` value (as in, the value might just be `Aggravated assault`). In those cases the count should be 1. As of right now, when your code hits those values, I'm getting `-Inf` for the value of `convictions_total`

Comment: You're welcome! Please supplement your post with an example of this situation so that I may adjust accordingly.

Comment: edited to include the third type of entry.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this row. When `str_extract` does not find a digit in the code assigning a vector to the name `convictions_total` it returns `character(0)`, which has no length. `as.numeric(character(0))` will convert this to `numeric(0)`, which also has no length. The default behavior of the `max` function with a zero length vector is to return `-Inf` (note, `min` by default will return `+Inf`). I simply changed the comparison to take advantage of this default behavior to be `max(..., 1)`, which in that specific case will resolve to `max(-Inf, 1)` and return `1`.

Comment: You will get unexpected behavior if you have a row with multiple unnumbered counts. For example: `"Aggravated Assault; Human Trafficking"` would have a value of `1` in `convictions_total`. Maybe this is expected since the number for `convictions_total` does not match the number of conviction columns for the fourth row in your current example.